# Python + QT or GTK + Material design. Is it possible?

Tags: python, qt, material-design

As I can see, QT has an official material design theme: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-material.html

I've been searching for Python QT bidings, and it looks like the most famous are PySide, PySide2 (in development) and PyQt4 or 5

I even found a repository which creates a python material design support but it's ugly and unmaintaned: https://github.com/ethanhs/material

I've read that it's possible to convert QT Creator ui files to python code. Is it possible t use Qt Creator to create a material design interface and compile to python code OR save as XML and import using a python qt library?

I've found some material design themes for GTK, but they are installabe themes for GNOME, not something that would be default in the application look. So GTK is less desirable because I'm constrained to GNOME guidelines.

Do you have another possible solution in mind even if it doesn't involve QT or GTK? Note that, however, video displaying is necessary.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Qt Quick Controls 2 is part of QML so it can be used together with PyQt5 and PySide2, in SO there are many examples. This is an example:
 https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/586e25c95bc5014874c58389c12947bf77037afc/PyQt%20Material%20Qml

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks. But which dependencies I must install? For exampke, where does pyrcc5 comes from?

Comment: pyrcc5 is part of PyQt5 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqt5-tools

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks. Now these are the errors: https://pastebin.com/kiLCDSqk have you had anything like that?

Comment: @eyllanesc sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5  
sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools

Comment: What version of PyQt5 do you have installed? What is your OS? How have you installed PyQt5?

Comment: Install all the packages you get when you run: `apt-cache search pyqt5`

Comment: If you have PyQt5 greater than or equal to 5.7 you can use those modules, but to do so, install the packages I told you.

Comment: @eyllanesc I did sudo apt install -y python3-pyqt5* and now I only get "module QtQuick.Controls.Material is not installed"

Comment: @eyllanesc also, my version is 5.7

Comment: @eyllanesc I summarized the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944407/trouble-using-qml-material-design-qtquick-controls-material-is-not-installed would be glad if you could help :) thank you