# Trouble using QML material design: "QtQuick.Controls.Material" is not installed

Tags: qt, qml

I'm following [this](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/586e25c95bc5014874c58389c12947bf77037afc/PyQt%20Material%20Qml) tutorial and I'm having a lot of QML module errors. I had to modify to `QtQuick.Controls 1.1` because `2.0, 2.1, 2.3` wouldn't work. Here's my QML now:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1
```

Now I get only

```
"QtQuick.Controls.Material" is not installed
```

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.1 and my `PyQt` reports version `5.7`. Qt's [website](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-material.html) says:

```
Import Statement:   import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3
Since:  Qt 5.7
```

but it won't work. Since I have `Qt 5.7` I should be able to use material design as the site says. But I can't even use `QtQuick.Controls 2.x`.

I don't wanna install Qt 5.8 because then my app won't be compatible with older linuxes. I need to use 5.7.

How should I make this work?

**UPDATE:**

After trying on my machine and losing track of what I had installed I created a docker container to test it:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ARG SIP_LINK=https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/sip/sip-4.19.7/sip-4.19.7.tar.gz

ARG PYQT5_LINK=https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.10/PyQt5_gpl-5.10.tar.gz

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential make wget ca-certificates \
    python3 python3-dev \
    qt5-default qml-module-qtquick-controls libqt5qml5 \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#SIP INSTALLAITON

RUN wget --progress=bar:force -O sip.tar.gz $SIP_LINK \
    && mkdir sip \
    && tar -xzvf sip.tar.gz -C sip --strip-components=1 \
    && rm sip.tar.gz \
    && cd sip \
    && python3 configure.py && make && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf sip

#PYQT5 INSTALLAITON

RUN wget --progress=bar:force -O pyqt5.tar.gz $PYQT5_LINK \
    && mkdir pyqt5 \
    && tar -xzvf pyqt5.tar.gz -C pyqt5 --strip-components=1 \
    && rm pyqt5.tar.gz \
    && cd pyqt5 \
    && python3 configure.py --confirm-license && make && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf pyqt5

WORKDIR /home/project

ENTRYPOINT "/bin/bash"
```

When I do

```
docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /home/lz/project:/home/project -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY test
```

and do `./main.py` (I'm following main.py from [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/586e25c95bc5014874c58389c12947bf77037afc/PyQt%20Material%20Qml), I get:

```
root@3054a751f04b:/home/prject# ./main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtQml import *
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtQml'
```

The packages `qml-module-qtquick-controls libqt5qml5` were added just to try make it work but it didn't help

**UPDATE 2:**
After adding the package `python3-pyqt5.qtquick`, I now get only the error:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///home/project/main.qml:4 module "QtQuick.Controls.Material" is not installed

process 12: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: UUID file '/etc/machine-id' should contain a hex string of length 32, not length 0, with no other text
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
```

**However, I shouldn't have to add python3 qt packages because I'm building them**

Comment: If you can't load `QtQuick.Controls 2.0` or higher then there is neither any need nor any possibility to load `QtQuick.Controls.Material`. There is no need, since it only works with the new style `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` and it is not possible, since it is only installed if there is `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` installed - since it is part of it.

Comment: Usually in your qt installation dir there should be somewhere a directory `qml/QtQuick/Controls.2` and a subdirectory of it `Material` - check that please.

Comment: Until recently, Ubuntu came with Qt5.6, which did not include QtQuick.Controls 2.x and therefore not with QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.x - I don't know when or whether this has changed.

Comment: @derM I have qtquick/controls.2 but no material folder in it. Please see a summary of what I'm doing: https://pastebin.com/FxqQKKc8

Comment: I'm using the latest ubuntu, which should have materials, I guess. Anyway, I'm also trying to install the newest library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983281/easiest-way-to-install-latest-qt-on-ubuntu but I didn t have success yet

Comment: You might try to build your QtQuick.Controls from source: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/ - you can see the materials directory in `src/imports/controls/material`

Comment: Install `qml-module-qtquick-controls2` instead of `qml-module-qtquick-controls`.

Comment: @jpnurmi this package does not exist in unbutu

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/qml-module-qtquick-controls2

Comment: @jpnurmi you're right. Changed the docker to bionic and it installed. However, now I get: file:///home/project/view.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
file:///home/project/view.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
file:///home/project/view.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
file:///home/project/view.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed

Comment: @jpnurmi ok, now I see. I added qml-module-qtquick2 qml-module-qtquick-window2 and it worked :)

Comment: @jpnurmi please add an answer so I can reward you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct Ubuntu package for Qt Quick Controls 2 is [qml-module-qtquick-controls2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/qml-module-qtquick-controls2). This package includes the Material style.

Comment: In the end I also needed the window package. Here's the summary of the packages (which only worked on newer ubuntus, bionic for example): python3 python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtquick 
qt5-default qml-module-qtquick-controls2 libqt5qml5 qml-module-qtquick2 qml-module-qtquick-window2

Comment: Looks like a missing dependency declaration in the Ubuntu package. Qt declares the following dependencies in its qmldir files: QtQuick.Controls -> QtQuick.Templates -> QtQuick.Window -> QtQuick.

Comment: In Fedora speak thats: qt6-qtquickcontrols2-devel and/or qt6-qtquickcontrols2

Answer (score 0):

According to the  [Qt Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-index.html#versions) for `QtQuick.Controls` versions, you should probably import `QtQuick 2.7` instead of `2.0` when using `Qt 5.7`:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
```

Comment: somebody once commented it here and deleted. Here's the output when I do like you said: QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///home/project/pycam.qml:1 module "QtQuick" version 2.7 is not installed

process 11: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: UUID file '/etc/machine-id' should contain a hex string of length 32, not length 0, with no other text
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.

Comment: the dbus error seems related to xorg, I think it happens because I'm inside docker but I don't think it's related to qt

Comment: You can import whatever QtQuick version you want, as long as you don't use features of a newer version. Since `QtQuick.Controls 2.0` and `QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0` with newer features are imported seperately, you can use `QtQuick 2.0. Since `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` and `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` are completely different and `QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.x` builds upon `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` you need to (be able to) import `QtQuick.Controls 2.x`. You can import both versions of `QtQuick.Controls` `1.x` and `2.x`, preferably by giving (one of) them an alias.