# Easiest way to install latest QT on ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, package

I need to install QT 5.10 on my ubuntu docker container. Compiling from source is out of question because it takes hours and my computer almost fried 2 times trying to do it until it ran ut of memory.

Does the QT installer from https://www.qt.io/download installs the libs for 5.10? If so, is there a way to install in a non graphical way? Since I'm in docker, I need an aautomated way to install it, but the .sh that is downloaded from the website is hundreads of megabytes long, so I can't read it to see if I can pass commands to automatically install it.

I think there's a PPA with qt available but I need a really thrustworthy source to get these libs. Debian is even worse in up to date packages.

Answer (score 3):

Try in light of: [headless unattended installation](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-166)

As for Qt5.9.1

```
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev libassimp-dev libfontconfig1 libdbus-1-3 wget
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.1/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.9.1.run
chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.9.1.run
./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.9.1.run
```

Comment: what's libassimp-dev? Doesn't exist on ubuntu

Comment: is there a way to prevent installation of qt creator and other things? I just need the libraries

Comment: It seems to try to start the display: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Aborted (core dumped)